# Are there any Amazon Silk demo videos showing tiled mapservice performance?

Tags: map-service, amazon-ec2

After reading about [Amazon's Silk browser](http://www.pcworld.com/article/240740/amazons_new_silk_browser_explained.html), it seems like this might work really well serving map tiles that are stored in S3.  Does anyone know of any video from a live demo showing a web mapping app running in EC2 using S3?

Preferably it would be an app with a public url that I could compare performance on a different device.